# Use async with drupal_http_request()

Tags: 7, http-request

I need to make an asynchronous call with `drupal_http_request()`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

With [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x) this is not possible. But you can have a look at the module [HTTP Parallel Request & Threading Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/httprl) which allows you to do non-blocking requests.

From the module page:

> Using stream_select() it will send http requests out in parallel. These requests can be made in a blocking or non-blocking way. Blocking will wait for the http response; Non-Blocking will close the connection not waiting for the response back. The API for httprl is similar to the Drupal 7 version of drupal_http_request().

Comment: I happen to know the module as I have used it in the past. But apart from that, the way of finding it would literally be: 1. Got to the API doc for [drupal_http_request](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7.x), 2. Search for "blocking" on that page ;)